# Converting IMges into Flash (.swf) using C# MVC

Tags: c#, flash, asp.net-mvc-5

I am making a web application in MVC 5 C# in which i have to programmatically convert images into .swf file.

I searched a lot but couldn't fine one. Can anyone please tell me the solution or link would be helpful.. Thanks!

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?... Anyway an SWF is just a "container" with AS3 code, sound, images, vector shapes etc. So if you want only to put JPEG bytes inside an SWF's bytes you can check **[SWF Format Specifications](http://wwwimages.adobe.com/www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/swf/pdf/swf-file-format-spec.pdf)**. See Chapter 8 on page 137. You want "DefineBitsJPEG3" method explained on page 139. Create bytes for that tag followed by inserting bytes of your JPEG image. You need SWF header bytes also etc etc...

Comment: In short.. 1) Make SWF header bytes (see page 27 for advice).. 2) Make bytes for a  `DefineBitsJPEG3` tag.. 3) Insert your JPEG bytes (starts with bytes `FFD8` later ends with `FFD9`).. There now you converted JPG to SWF (techically correct is "contained" since it cannot be "converted" since no pixels in SWF format). Now export (save) all the bytes as myFile.swf and test in browser or whatever you use...